Receive AWS SNS messages with Basic Authentication using Azure API Manager
I need to secure communications between an 3rd Party AWS SNS service and my API using basic authentication.
I have setup an API in Azure API Management with basic authentication and a mock response. I have configured logging and I can see successful inbound requests via postman with a POST message to https://user:password@myurl.com/sns
I am working with a 3rd party who has configured AWS SNS notifications.  Inbound messages from SNS fail with an error:
Header Authorization was not found in the request. Access denied.
How do I configure basic authentication with AWS SNS?

To configure basic authentication with AWS SNS, you need to pass the access key as an HTTP header or a URL query parameter.
To pass the access key as an HTTP header, you need to include the Authorization header with the value Basic . The username and password should be replaced with your REST API endpoint's username and password, respectively.
To pass the access key as a URL query parameter, you need to include the aeg-sas-key parameter with the value of your REST API endpoint's access key.
